# IDocumentSession.SaveChanges() vs Transactions

Tags: c#, transactions, ravendb, unit-of-work

The raven client (`IDocumentSession`) doesn't send anything to the server until `SaveChanges` is called. So it could be considered as a UnitOfWork implementation, right?

Am I correct in thinking that the only difference between `SaveChanges` and `Transaction.Commit` is that the latter rolls back all changes if something failed during the commit?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are doing a single operation, there is no need to use an explicit transaction since the `SaveChanges` results in a implicit transaction.

If you make use of `System.Transactions`, you can perform multiple operations, ie multiple `SaveChanges` using the same transaction. Raven will manage the transactions over http using a request header.

Read more in the docs: http://ravendb.net/documentation/docs-api-transactions

Comment: Kul med andra svenska RavenDb nissar ;) (the comment doesn't say much, just ignore it if you aren't Swedish)

Answer (score 7):

`SaveChanges()` operate in a transaction, so if you are modifying multiple documents, all of them would be saved, or none would.
Also support `System.Transactions`, but usually it is not needed.